# "Ionic / Angular 2: Access object: Error in ./Page1 class Page1 - caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I try to write an application in Ionic: here's the code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Welcome</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Let's start</h3>

  <p>
    Some text here.
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li> {{ Schueler.name }} </li>
  </ul>

</ion-content>
```

This is the typescript definition:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController , NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Student } from '../../app/student.components';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    var Schueler = new Student('Doldi');
    console.log(Schueler.name)
  }
}
```

The instantiation of the new Schueler works fine, I can print it out in the console.

I get an error: "Error in ./Page1 class Page1 - caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
I thought it is possible to access the instance Schueler in the HTML code.

Comment: You should use `Safe Navigation Operator` on page `<li> {{ Schueler?.name }} </li>`

Comment: Thanks, does compile now, but I get an empty output, though in the browser console I can analyze the object, which is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign it correctly. Currently you have an open ended variable `Schueler` which is equal to a new instance of Student. Although it works fine as a `console.log` in order to pass it to the view you need to assign it.

```
export class Page1{
   studentName:string; // assignable element for view

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      let Schueler = new Student('Doldi');
      this.studentName = Schueler.name;
   }
}
```

And then in your view

```
<ul>
  <li> {{ studentName.name }} </li>
</ul>
```

You can also instantiate the `Student` object in the `constructor()`

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public student: Student) { 
    this.student = student('Doldi');
}
```

....

```
<ul>
  <li> {{ student.name }} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instantiation in the constructor doesn't work, or do you mean this.student = new Student("Doldi") ?